# Swift: Should I prefer using the default imageView, textLabel and detailTextLabel in UITableVIewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
@available(iOS 2.0, *)
public class UITableViewCell : UIView, NSCoding, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
   @available(iOS 3.0, *)
   public init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
   public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
   @available(iOS 3.0, *)
   public var imageView: UIImageView? { get }
   @available(iOS 3.0, *)
   public var textLabel: UILabel? { get }
   @available(iOS 3.0, *)
   public var detailTextLabel: UILabel? { get }   
   public var contentView: UIView { get }
```

There're already an imageView, a textLabel and a detailTextLabel derived from UITableViewCell. So should I prefer using the default elements (imageView, textLabel and detailTextLabel) or create new?

For example:

If it only needs one image view in a cell. Should I use the imageView directly or create a `var myImageView = UIImageView()` ?

Which is better?

Note!!!
 There's one more question, why it occurs error when I add detailTextLabel with `let cell = AarioTableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "AarioTableViewCell")`?

```
class AarioTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var selfDefinedTextLabel = UILabel()
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    contentView.addSubview(imageView!)         // derived imageView

    contentView.addSubview(textLabel!)         // derived textLabel

    contentView.addSubview(detailTextLabel!)  // Error!!!

    contentView.addSubview(selfDefinedTextLabel)  // re-declared

    }

}
```

Comment: it depends what you're going to do with it, probably always best to create your own...

Comment: Depends. If your requirement match how the defaults display those information go with it. Defaults are easy to use and works better on features like accessibility for free. Whenever you wants more customization later you can implement without much hassle.